# unwanted <br> tags appearing on web page that are visible using google chrome inspect, but not visible in the app's code

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, google-console-developer

I'm having an issue where my web page is being effected with multiple `br` tags. I have checked through all my code but they only appear when I inspect the code via google chrome inspect.

I've tried to delete them using the google console but they keep coming back. Any ideas how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

[invisable 
 tags are appearing in the console but not in the apps code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGCne.png)

[google console with 
 tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuSsA.png)

Comment: both those screenshots show a `br` tag after the `td` tag for `record.Label`....   -- Are any conversions from `newline` to `br` going on somewhere in the code?

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, ive just added a image of what the console is displaying. the problem is there are about 20 br tags appearing underneath the h1 tag "purchase history" and its causing a huge space between the h1 and the table its self.. thanks

Comment: Looks like Chrome tries to make sense out of the `<br>` in a `<tr>`. Just remove the `<br>` after `<%= order.record.Label %></td>` and you should be fine. Hint: a `<br>` is not allowed inside of `<tr>`: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp

Comment: Can you show the code that is generating this output please

Comment: thanks a million. with the loop i had set up. it created multiple <br> tags. many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<br>` is not allowed inside of a `<tr>`. Looks like Chrome tries to make sense out of the `<br>` in one of your `<tr>`s.

Just remove the `<br>` after

```
<td><%= order.record.Label %></td>
```

and you should be fine.

Hint: A `<tr>` is only allowed to contain [one or more `<th>` or `<td>` elements](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp).